# Хочу заменить буквы в строке

Tags: c++, qt, строки, указатели

Надо преработать строку добавить дополнительные буквы либо заменить имеющиеся .

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <QDebug>

 #include <cstring>

 MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
  {
        char* str = "Hello World";
int count = strlen(str);
printf("Количество символов в строке \"Hello World\" = %u\n", count);
for (int i = 0; i<count; ++i)
{
    qDebug() << "Это эламент chSave ["<< i << "]"<<str[i];
    if(str[i] == "l")
    {
        str[i] = "W";
    }
    else if ( str[i] == "2")
    {
        str[i] = "W";
    }
  }
        ui->setupUi(this);
  }

   MainWindow::~MainWindow()
 {
     delete ui;
 }
```

Выпрыгивает две ошибки С2446, С2040 . Не могу сними справиться .
Пожалуйста помогите .

Comment: строка - это массив символов. А Вы присваиваете i-ому элементу строки (т.е. символу) строку.
Двойные кавычки замените на одинарные, чтобы Ваши односимвольные строки превратить в символы.

Comment: Это было навскидку. Т.к. проверять и дебажить нет ни времени, ни желания, а строки, где ошибки, Вы не указали. Ну и за бессмысленность и очевидность вопроса -1.

Comment: @timob256 Показывайте текст сообщений об ошибках. Почему кто-то должен знать сообщения об ошибках вашего компилятора наизусть?

Answer (score 2):

В данном предложении

```
char* str = "Hello World";
```

вы объявили указатель на строковый литерал.

В C++ строковые литералы имеют типы константных символьных массивов. Поэтому правильно было бы записать это объявление следующим образом

```
const char* str = "Hello World";
```

Строковые литералы в C++ неизменяемые. Любая попытка изменить строковый литерал ведет к неопределенному поведению программы.

Вам следовало объявить символьный массив вместо указателя на строковый литерал:

```
char str[] = "Hello World";
```

Имейте в виду, что будет лучше указывать префикс пространства имен `std`, у стандартных C-функций, так как не обязательно, что компилятор помещает их в глобальное пространство имен.

Поэтому правильно будет написать

```
size_t count = std::strlen(str);
```

К тому же вы в предложениях как это

```
str[i] = "W";
```

или это

```
if(str[i] == "l")
```

некорректно используете строковый литерал вместо символьного литерала

```
str[i] = 'W';
```

или

```
if(str[i] == 'l')
```